# Continuity and differentiability of $f(x,y)$

Tags: analysis

Explore continuity and differentiability of the function

$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
\dfrac {xy\sin x}{x^2+y^2} & \text{$(x,y)\not=(0,0)$} \\
0 & \text{$(x,y)=(0,0)$}
\end{cases}.$

In $(x,y)\not=(0,0)$, function is continuous, as 
quotient of two continuous functions.

I am checking in $(x,y)=(0,0)$.

Well, I think this function is not continuous, because

we can see that

$\left\lvert \dfrac {xy\sin x}{x^2+y^2}\right\rvert \le \left\lvert \dfrac {xy}{x^2+y^2}\right\rvert.$

Let $\left(\frac{1}{k},\frac{1}{k}\right) \rightarrow (0,0)$, where $k\rightarrow \infty.$

And we get

$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} {\dfrac{\frac{1}{k^2}}{\frac{1}{k^2}+\frac{1}{k^2}}} = \frac{1}{2} \not= 0=f(0,0).$

If a function is discontinuous, then it is not differentiable.

Is that correct?

Comment: The function is continuous at and around $(0,0)$. Making the shift to polar coordinates,we find that $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} = f(x,y) = 0$.

Comment: $\frac{r^2(cosx)(sin^2x)}{r^2} = (cosx)(sin^2x) = 0 $ where $x \rightarrow 0$ ??

Comment: Not quite. $\sin(x) = \sin(r\cos(\theta))$.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote

$$\left\lvert \dfrac {xy\sin x}{x^2+y^2}\right\rvert \le \left\lvert \dfrac {xy}{x^2+y^2}\right\rvert.$$

But clearly we have a better estimate: $$\left\lvert \dfrac {xy\sin x}{x^2+y^2}\right\rvert \le |\sin x|\left\lvert \dfrac {xy}{x^2+y^2}\right\rvert.$$

That implies continuity at $(0,0)$.

**Added later**: Suppose $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0).$ Then

$$f(x,y) = f(0,0) + \nabla f (0,0)\cdot (x,y) + o((x^2 +y^2)^{1/2}).$$

But note $f(0,0)=0$ and $\nabla f (0,0)=(0,0).$ On the ray $y=x, x>0$ we then have

$$\frac{x^2\sin x}{2x^2} = (\sin x)/2 = o((2x^2)^{1/2}) = o(x).$$

Since $(\sin x)/x\to 1,$ we have a contradiction.

Comment: I added a bit about differentiability.

Answer (score 0):

No. $\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$ is bounded and $\sin x\to 0$ as $(x,y)\to (0,0)$. Hence the function is continuous at $(0,0)$. You definitely need to check whether it is differentiable at $(0,0)$.

Comment: $\frac{df}{dx}(0,0) = lim t \rightarrow 0 \frac{f(t,0)-f(0)}{t}=0 , \frac{df}{dy}(0,0) = lim t \rightarrow 0 \frac{f(0,t)-f(0)}{t}=0$ 
                                                              
                Both partial derivatives are continuous, so I have to check $\frac{df}{dx}(x,y)$ and $\frac{df}{dy}(x,y)$ ? Or from the 
differential mapping (sorry I don't know how it is in english, I hope u will understand) definition?

Comment: You only showed both the partial derivatives exist. I would be surprised if they are continuous at $(0,0)$. You need to refer to the definition of differentiability directly.

Comment: Yes indeed, so $lim h=(h1,h2) \rightarrow 0 \frac{\lVert f(h1,h2)-f(0,0)-A(h1,h2)\lVert}{\lVert h \lVert}= ?? $ I don't know what next, how to calculate.... $A=gradf(0,0)=(0,0)$

Comment: Let us suppose $f$ is differentiable. Then its differential $A$ has to be zero as you calculated the partial derivatives. But then we get a contradiction since $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\|f(h)\|}{\|h\|}$ does not exist.

Comment: Basically the denominator and the numerator are of the same order. So along different directions the limit will be different.

Comment: But $lim h \rightarrow 0 \frac{\lVert f(h)\lVert}{\lVert h\lVert} = 0 = f(0,0)$ ??

Comment: How do you get that? (Please avoid extended discussions in comments. You can edit your question to give more information.)

Comment: Since $sin(h1) h1 \rightarrow 0 = 0$?

Comment: Can you write $\|f(h)\|/\|h\|$ explicitly? Please write your thoughts in the question not in the comment.